# Grails 2.2.2 createCriteria throwing error

Tags: grails, groovy

I have looked over the internet but didn't find anything except this [Jira Issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4777) Im using **Grails 2.2.2** the issue affect **1.7.10** but is still not `resolved`  so..

**The problem**

When I change `eq('code', 'guitar')` to `'in'('code', ["guitar", "bass", "flute"])`

**I get the error :**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

**The working code**

```
//this code is working like expected 
def c = Project.createCriteria();
this.ids = c.list {
    projections {
        property 'id'
    }
    instruments{
        eq('code', 'guitar')
    }
}
```

**The NOT working code**

```
//when I change the code to this one I get the error.
def c = Project.createCriteria();
this.ids = c.list {
    projections {
        property 'id'
    }
    instruments{
        //### This line create the problem!!
        'in'('code', ["guitar", "bass", "flute"])
    }
}
```

**The full stacktrace error:**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
Message: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    Line | Method
->> 1618 | invokeMethod     in grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    230 | search           in sound.domain.ProjectPagingService$$EOgryxiS
|    193 | search . . . . . in com.sound.ProjectController$$EOgrT45Y
|    150 | invoke           in net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper
|    281 | invoke . . . . . in net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler
|     82 | doFilterInternal in com.linkedin.grails.profiler.ProfilerFilter
|    202 | doFilter . . . . in net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter
|    180 | doFilter         in     ''
|   1145 | runWorker . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be your use of double-quotes in the list, try this instead:

```
this.ids = Project.withCriteria {

    projections {
        property 'id'
    }

    instruments{
        'in'('code', ['guitar', 'bass', 'flute'])
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes !!!!!!!!!!!! :))) Thank you !! BTW the array is created dynamically with params.entrySet().findAll {
           it.key.startsWith("musicalStyles")
        }.each {
    
           ms = "$it.value";
          
        }

`ms`is the `Array` do you know how to change double cote by simple code ?

Comment: This seems like a separate question, can you make a new post and paste the link here?